# ImageCMS Programming/Scripting Language

Tags: content-management-system

I need to modify an element on a web page, build on some sort of custom management system called ImageCMS, but I cannot determine what programming or scripting language is being used by the system.

Could you please check the code snippet below and show me the right direction? :)

```
 <select name="variant" id="variantSwitcher">
  {foreach $variants as $key => $productVariant} 
  <option value="{echo $productVariant->getId()}">
    {if $productVariant->getName()}
    {echo ShopCore::encode($productVariant->getName())}
    {else:}
    {echo ShopCore::encode($model->getName())}
    {/if}
  </option>
  {/foreach}
</select>
```

Comment: looks like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison)

Comment: Yes it is :) Thanks a lot! Please post your answer to let me accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it might be [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison)

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot :)